# Graphing electric potential of a ring of charge using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging

My code is not plotting the correct contour plot for a plane perpendicular to a ring of charge running through its center properly. **My problem is that the contour plot is not filling 2D space**.

I've made two versions of code, one uses a for loop to calculate a 
Riemann sum and the other simply uses the sum command. Both rely on the 
'subs' command for substituting values from a meshgrid into my expression  for V (electric potential).

Version 1 (using for loop):

```
%% Computing a symbolic expression for V for anywhere in space

syms x y z % phiprime is angle that an elemental dq of the circular 
charge is located at, x,y and z are arbitrary points in space outside the 
charge distribution

N = 200; % number of increments to sum
R = 2; % radius of circle is 2 meters

dphi = 2*pi/N; % discretizing the circular line of charge which spans 2pi

             integrand = 0;
for phiprime = 0:dphi:2*pi  

% phiprime ranges from 0 to 2pi in increments of dphi

integrand = integrand + dphi./(sqrt(((x - R.*cos(phiprime) )).^2 + ((y - 
R.*sin(phiprime) ).^2) + z.^2));

end

intgrl = sum(integrand); 
% uncessary but harmless step that I leave to show that I am using the 
sum of the above expression for each dphi    

eps0 = 8.854e-12;
kC = 1/(4*pi*eps0);
rhol = 1*10^-9; % linear charge density

    Vtot = kC*rhol*R.*intgrl; % symbolic expression for Vtot

%% Graphing V & E in plane perpedicular to ring & passing through center

[Y1, Z1] = meshgrid(-4:.5:4, -4:.5:4);
Vcont1 = subs(Vtot, [x,y,z], {0,Y1,Z1}); % Vcont1 stands for V contour; 1 
is because I do the plane of the ring next

contour(Y1,Z1,Vcont1)
xlabel('y - axis [m]')
ylabel('z - axis [m]')
title('V in a plane perpendicular to a ring of charge (N = 200)')
str = {'Red line is side view', 'of ring of charge'};
text(-1,2,str)

hold on
% visually displaying line of charge on plot
circle =  rectangle('Position',[-2 0 4 .1],'Curvature',[1,1]); 
set(circle,'FaceColor',[1, 0, 0],'EdgeColor',[1, 0, 0]);

% taking negative gradient of V and finding symbolic equations for Ex, Ey 
and Ez
        g = gradient(-1.*(kC*rhol*R.*intgrl),[x,y,z]); 

%% now substituting all the values of the 2D coordinate system for the 
symbolic x and y variables to get numeric values for Ex and Ey
Ey1 = subs(g(2), [x y z], {0,Y1,Z1});
Ez1 = subs(g(3), [x y z], {0,Y1,Z1});

E1 = sqrt(Ey1.^2 + Ez1.^2); % full numeric magnitude of E in y-z plane

Eynorm1 = Ey1./E1; % This normalizes the electric field lines
Eznorm1 = Ez1./E1;  

quiver(Y1,Z1,Eynorm1,Eznorm1);
hold off
```

Version 2 (using sum command):

```
syms x y z
R = 2; % radius of circle is 2 meters
N=100;
dphi = 2*pi/N; % discretizing the circular line of charge which spans 2pi

phiprime = 0:dphi:2*pi; %phiprime ranges from 0 to 2pi in increments of 
dphi

integrand = dphi./(sqrt(((x - R.*cos(phiprime) )).^2 + ((y - 
R.*sin(phiprime) ).^2) + z.^2));

phiprime = 0:dphi:2*pi;
intgrl =   sum(integrand); % Reimann sum performed here

eps0 = 8.854e-12;
kC = 1/(4*pi*eps0);
rhol = 1*10^-9; % linear charge density

Vtot = kC*rhol*R.*intgrl; % symbolic expression for Vtot
```

Everything else after that point for version 2 is the same as version 1 (substituting for the symbols x,y,z etc)

I would post images of what the code produces but apparently you need 10 reputation for that. Thanks stackoverflow. This will be much more confusing to understand without the images.

The vector field produced by my code is correct while the contour plot seems to use only a few points around the ends of the ring and connect them with straight lines in a strange diamond shape. I can't get it to fill space.

I receive no error messages. The contour lines accumulate around the ends of the ring (where the potential would approach infinity) in a strange diamond shape but aren't graphed anywhere else. I need the contour plot to fill the 2D grid

Answer (score 0):

I received a solution to this question from MATLAB's community and posted about it here:

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32834/graphing-electric-potential-of-a-ring-of-charge-using-matlab-help/32842#32842

I would post here but this "you can't post images because you don't have enough reputation" thing would make my explanation too abstract and difficult to understand so go take a look if you are having MATLAB contour plot issues and want to *see* my problem and solution